# Completed feature-request gets closed as off-topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta, off-topic

[This feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270912/i-mustache-you-a-question) was marked *status-completed* and then it got closed as *off-topic*. If it was really *off-topic* then it should not have been tagged completed. To me that is really strange, maybe I am missing something here. Can anyone please shed some light on it.

Comment: Maybe just to prevent answers on it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman possibly. Could have been protected as well.

Comment: That doesn't prevent answering it.

Comment: You probably mean locking.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft oh yes, thanks for correcting. Could have been locked.

Comment: That would prevent voting too.

Answer (score 2):

That feature request/question was stupid and inane (IMESHO, of course).

Sadly, this is what we should expect during Winter Bash.

I find it a bit troubling that Shog9 is enabling some of the worst aspects of Winter Bash. Sure, Winter Bash should be fun, but we should still be focusing on making **positive** contributions to the network. Some users instead see the hunt for hats as an opportunity to treat the network like a cheap motel room. This wouldn't be tolerated in June, and I don't know why it is tolerated now.

So I agree: that question should not have been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

I, for one, am glad that balpha (and Werner) closed that question. One could argue that balpha should have deleted it outright. But closing it lets 20K users start voting to remove it (and later 10K users if it still exists), and gives 125 rep users the chance to add to the downvote count. In short, more users can voice their dissatisfaction.

Locking the question would fix it in its current state. This implies that it has content worth preserving, which is an assessment I do not agree with.